# Data Structures for Creating BIG Data in R

Tags: r, data-structures, bigdata

I'm writing a gene level analysis script in R and I'll have to handle large amounts of data.

My initial idea was to create a super list structure, a set of lists within lists. Essentially the structure is

```
#12.8 mins
list[[1:8]][[1:1000]][[1:6]][[1:1000]]
```

This is huge and takes in excess of 12 mins purely to set up the data structure. Stream lining this process, I can get it down to about 1.6 mins when setting up one value of the 1:8 list, so essentially...

```
#1.6 mins
list[[1:1]][[1:1000]][[1:6]][[1:1000]]
```

Normally, I'd create the structure as and when it's needed, on the fly, however, I'm distributing the 1:1000 steps which means, I don't know which order they'll come back in.

Are there any other packages for handling the creation of this level of data?
Could I use any more efficient data structures in my approach?

I apologise if this seems like the wrong approach entirely, but this is my first time handling big data in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that lists are vectors, and like any other vector, they can have a `dim` attribute.

```
l <- vector("list", 8 * 1000 * 6 * 1000)
dim(l) <- c(8, 1000, 6, 1000)
```

This is effectively instantaneous. You access individual elements with `[[`, eg `l[[1, 2, 3, 4]]`.

Comment: fantastic, this is instantaneous and creates the data structure I need.

Answer (score 2):

A different strategy is to create a vector and a partitioning, e.g., to represent

```
list(1:4, 5:7)
```

as

```
l = list(data=1:7, partition=c(4, 7))
```

then one can do vectorized calculations, e.g.,

```
logl = list(data=log(l$data), partition = l$partition)
```

and other clever things. This avoids creating complicated lists and the iterations that implies. This approach is formalized in the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/) [IRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html) package `*List` classes.

```
> library(IRanges)
> l <- NumericList(1:4, 5:7)
> l
NumericList of length 2
[[1]] 1 2 3 4
[[2]] 5 6 7
> log(l)
NumericList of length 2
[[1]] 0 0.693147180559945 1.09861228866811 1.38629436111989
[[2]] 1.6094379124341 1.79175946922805 1.94591014905531
```

One idiom for working with this data is to `unlist`, transform, then `relist`; both `unlist` and `relist` are inexpensive, so the long-hand version of the above is `relist(log(unlist(l)), l)`

Depending on your data structure, the `DataFrame` class may be appropriate, e.g., the following can be manipulated like a `data.frame` (subset, etc) but contains *List elements.

```
> DataFrame(Sample=c("A", "B"), VariableA=l, LogA=log(l))
DataFrame with 2 rows and 3 columns
       Sample     VariableA                                              LogA
  <character> <NumericList>                                     <NumericList>
1           A     1,2,3,...          0,0.693147180559945,1.09861228866811,...
2           B         5,6,7 1.6094379124341,1.79175946922805,1.94591014905531
```

For genomic data where the coordinates of genes (or other features) on chromosomes is of fundamental importance, the [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package and GRanges / GRangesList classes are appropriate.